# Can I use primary key in association for find Waterline

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I've created two models with associations:

**User.js**

```
attributes: {
  fullname: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },

  username: {
    type: 'string',
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },

  email: {
    type: 'email',
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },

  mothertongue: {
    type: 'string'
  },

  passports: {
    collection: 'Passport',
    via: 'user'
  },

  words: {
    collection: 'Words',
    via: 'owners',
    dominant: true
  }
}
```

**Words.js**

```
attributes: {
  word: {
    type: 'string',
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },

  language: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },

  owners: {
    collection: 'User',
    via: 'words'
  }
}
```

When I'm searching about words owner someone he return back empty array

```
Words
  .find({
    owners: req.session.passport.user
  })
  .exec(function(err, data){
    if (err) {
      return res.send('error');
    }

    res.send(data);
})
```

Also I used `.populate('owners')` but don't work too.

Comment: Are you trying to find the words associated with a user, or are you trying to find which users are associated with a certain word?

Comment: I Want to show User's Words (like show words has owner id 1 but Can 1 Word Has many Users )

Answer (score 2):

To find the words a user has:

```
User.find(1).populate('words')
```

To find which users own a particular word, use

```
Word.find(id).populate('owners', {id : ...})
```

Comment: it's work but I want use populate for another association with word :(
okey , Another Question Can I Used add() & save() in  One-To-Many or any way instead of  add() & save() .

Comment: How ? I Put another .populate() after the first?

Comment: Yes. For example : 

`User.find(1).populate('passports').populate('words').exec(....)`

Comment: Sorry for my many Question :D and thank you , But I have another question if I want to get association form Second schema like

`User.find({id:1}).populate('words').populate('Words.translations')`

Comment: You can't do nested populations yet.  That is something still being worked on.  You can do something like `Words.find({user: 1}).populate('translations')`, or do another query once you get the first population.